# Табы на CSS

Tags: html, css

А как стилизовать табы при помощи CSS в такой вид?
[image]

Answer (score 5):

[Рисование фигур на CSS](http://web-answers.ru/questions-and-answers/html/figury/)

Кривые линии можно нарисовать бордером.

Comment: можно, но как же тени?

Comment: @vox: Тени можно сделать с `box-shadow`. Посмотрите мой ответ на вопрос [Блок со внутренней тенью лишь у двух краев ](http://hashcode.ru/questions/226954/html-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%8C-%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%B2). Там есть расширенный пример по созданию теней только для нескольких краев блока.

Answer (score 4):

Не идеальный вариант, но для начала: http://jsfiddle.net/coder13/bqLd9/. Работает в Chrome и Opera.

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-weight: 100;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: helvetica;
}
       
.tabs input[type=radio] {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}
.tabs {
    width: 650px;
    float: none;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 75px auto;
}
.tabs li{
    float: left;
}
.tabs label {
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 65px 8px 65px;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
    color: rgb(108,106,106);
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: 'Lily Script One', helveti;

    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
    
    
    
}

       
[id^=tab]:checked + label {
    box-shadow:  0 -5px 5px  -5px #000, -5px 0 5px  -5px #000;
    background: linear-gradient(#ececec 0%, #d2d2d3 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ececec 0%, #d2d2d3 100%);
    color: #000;
    top: 3px;
    
    z-index: 2
}
[id^=tab]:checked + label:after {
    
    width: 63px; height: 63px;
    box-shadow:  0 -5px 5px  -5px #000;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ececec 0%, #d2d2d3 50%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ececec 0%, #d2d2d3 50%);
    
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute; right: -27px; top: 13px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}       
[id^=tab]:checked ~ [id^=tab-content] {
    display: block;
}
.tab-content{
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 140%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    background: #d2d2d3;
    padding: 15px;
    min-height: 100px;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 43px;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
        <li>
            <input type="radio" checked name="tabs" id="tab1" />
          <label for="tab1">tab 1</label>
          <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content">
    
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2"/>
          <label for="tab2">tab 2</label>
          <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content">
            
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3"/>
          <label for="tab3">tab 3</label>
          <div id="tab-content3" class="tab-content">
            
          </div>
        </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: Круто конечно, но стоит ли так извращаться?

Comment: @Genson: Конечно нет, значительно проще сделать с картинками.

Answer (score 2):

1. Использовать картинку  для фона таба.
2. Использовать псевдоэлементы и рисовать в них треугольники. Не уверен правда на счёт градиентов и теней.

Comment: без картинки, тени и градиент обязательны :)

Comment: @vox вы говорите как HR, т.е. вам либо дали задание, либо вы ищете того, кто его выполнит, иначе непонятна уверенность в дуабельности (забыл как это по русски).

Comment: Стало интересно реализовать через псевдо треугольник с тенью и поворотом. Получился насколько убогий костыль, что не передать. Шаг влево вправо, всё расползается. При этом я ещё не дошёл до заливки градиента, потому что это отдельная песня. В итоге пришёл к выводу, что я бы сделал через картинку.

Comment: @eicto ясное дело этот вопрос относитя к моей работе.

Comment: не, когда надо сделать, таких деталей не выставляют. а-то можно сказать, "сделайте мне" без js и картинок "bullet holes" в div...

Answer (score 2):

Не думаю, что это реально без картинки. Да и вообще стоит ли оно того.
Тут целых две проблемы, решения которых я не вижу.

- Треугольник. Врядли к нему можно добавить тень.
- Сопоставление теней и градиентов. Тут же сплошной градиент на всю фигуру: и на закладку, и на треугольник закладки и на то, что ниже. Если у того, что ниже еще и неизвестна высота, то тут вообще беда. Не понятно, как "тянуть" градиент по вертикали.

На мой взгляд есть надежда в том, чтобы создать треугольник как квадрат, повернуть на 45 градусов его и каким-нибудь родительским оверфловом обрезать половину. Изначально расположить его внутри закладки на случай если трансформы не поддерживаются, чтобы его не было видно.

Еще можно попробовать пойти от обратного: создать сплошняковый градиент на всю фигуру и белым цветом перекрывать неактивные закладками.

Я бы для начала попробовал это сделать хоть как-нибудь, картинками. Тут повсплывает еще куча проблем с сопоставлением и тенями. Что будет, когда другая вкладка станет активной?